# Visualization of branched covering map between Riemann surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I was having a hard time imagine the picture of a branched covering, the locally $z^k$ description is more "real" or "1-dimension" to me. Anybody have a good picture/example to visualize this?

Answer (score 0):

This picture (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Riemann_sqrt.svg) gives you a pretty good idea of what $z \mapsto z^2$ looks like near $z=0$. For the general case $z \mapsto z^k$, there will be $k$ distinct sheets away from the origin, but they will all come together at $0$.